# Integration: Determine the area bounded by the curve $y=x(2-x)$ and the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

These are the steps I have worked out so far.

$$y=x(2-x)$$

$$ =2x - x^2$$

$$\int x^2 - \frac{x}{3} ^3$$

I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: What are the bounds of integration, if there are any?

Comment: I haven't been given any, that's where I am unsure where to proceed.

Comment: The area bounded by the curve and the x-axis has three components, two below the axis which are not bounded and on the upper half of the plane. Since the areas below are not bounded I would assume the calculation to be done on the bounded area between the curve and the axis.

Answer (score 1):

You have used integration notation correctly.

$$\int (2x - x^2)~\text{d}x = x^2 - \frac{x^3}{3} + C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  Notice that the integral sign is placed next to the quantity that is to be integrated, not its antiderivative.

The antiderivative is a function whose derivative is the given function.  Indeed, if we set 
$$F(x) = x^2 - \frac{x^3}{3} + C$$
for some constant $C$, then
$$F'(x) = 2x - x^2$$

As for the problem of finding the area bounded by the curve $y = x(2 - x)$ and the $x$-axis, notice that $y = x(2 - x)$ is a parabola that opens downwards with $x$-intercepts $x = 0$ and $x = 2$.  Its axis of symmetry is the average of the $x$-intercepts, which is $x = 1$.  The vertex lies on the axis of symmetry.  Substituting $1$ for $x$ in the equation $y = x(2 - x)$ yields $y = 1$, so the vertex is $(1, 1)$.  With that in mind, we can obtain the following graph.

[image: graph_of_parabola]

As Manuel DaGeo pointed out in the comments, the components of the graph below the $x$-axis are not bounded.  However, the component above the $x$-axis is.  Therefore, we wish to find the area of the region shown in yellow in the graph below.

[image: area_bounded_by_parabola_and_x-axis]

Notice that the $x$-coordinates of this region are bounded below by $0$ and above by $2$.  These are our limits of integration.  Hence, the area we wish to find is 
\begin{align*}
A & = \int_{0}^{2} x(2 - x)~\text{d}x\\
  & = \int_{0}^{2} (2x - x^2)~\text{d}x\\
  & = (x^2 - \frac{1}{3}x^3)~\bigg|_{0}^{2}\\
  & = \left(2^2 - \frac{1}{3} \cdot 2^3\right) - \left(0^2 - \frac{1}{3} \cdot 0^3\right)\\
  & = 4 - \frac{8}{3}\\
  & = \frac{4}{3}
\end{align*}

Comment: I was unsure how to determine the limits, that is where I was struggling. THanks this helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct. Here's how I'd approach it:

- First, find the bounds of integration. If we are assuming the area above the $x$-axis, find the points where $y=0$. The leftmost such point will be your lower bound of integration (call it $a$) and the rightmost such point will be your upper bound (call it $b$). You can tell by how the function is defined you will have two and only two such points and that it is a parabola.

> **Note:** if this is not what your question intends for the definition of the bounds, go by whatever definition the problem wants. If it gives a specific interval or something of the sort, use said interval and ignore my yammering about the zeroes of the function since I'm mostly just guessing as to what the problem wants.
>
> Said guess comes from how the function is already "factored" into $x(2-x)$ and mostly just recollecting on similar exercises I had in my calculus classes. That said, if possible, ask whoever gave you the problem for clarity.

- Next, set up your integral. You are seeking the area under the curve and thus want
  $$\int_a^b y dx = \int_a^b x(2-x)dx$$
  for whatever the bounds $a,b$ are. In general to find the (signed) area under a curve of a function $f$ you will find the integral of that function over a specified interval.
- Calculate the integral and use the fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate it.

Comment: I haven't been given the bounds of the integration. I assume I am required to determine the bounds myself but I am unsure where to find them.

If I had the bounds I can continue with the definite integration.

Comment: Usually the bounds have to be given in some sense. There's no real way to "determine" them (unless they're given in some vague sense like "between the zeros of the function"). Thus my guess is just that: that they want the area of the function that lies above the $x$ axis. Which, owing to the behavior of the function, would mean that you need to set the bounds to be the zeroes of the function.